# Not blurry TextView in blurry Layout

Tags: android

I'm trying to put some TextViews on black-transparent layer. 
To make the layout blurry, I set alpha(0.3) inside layout
It works well. The layout became transparent. 
But the problem is that the textview inside the layout also becomes blurry. 
How can I fix it?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#E6000000"
    android:alpha="0.3"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_feed_myPlant_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Error"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_feed_myPlant_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Mind adding a screenshot for clarity?

Comment: Try not using alpha instead use #80000000 for the parent layout color

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is take a relative layout and take a view which covers all of it and set the aplha to that view.Then you can take your linear layout and set it as the second child of the relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.3"
        android:background="#E6000000"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_feed_myPlant_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Error"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_feed_myPlant_time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I did this and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is Not really the best of doing it. But it will fix your problem

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/white">
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#E6000000"
       android:alpha="0.3"
    >
    <TextView
       />

    <TextView
       />
</LinearLayout>
```